Is there a way to show chart with axis of time-scale in chart.js?
I am trying to create a line chart with chart.js. The x axis is year. The following code
  const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

  new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'line',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            data: [
              { x: '1999', y: 120000},
              { x: '2007', y: 170000}, //5
              { x: '2008', y: 180000},
             ]
        }],
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        xAxes:[{type:'time'}]
      },
      plugins: {
         legend:{ display:false}
      }
    }
  });

show the data in the following chart

However, I would like to improve it:

Tick the x axis with scale of time, not as labels. That is, the 2007 tick should be close to the 2008 tick, not in the middle of 1999 and 2008.

If possible, show a smooth curve.



If you're using a newer (v3, v4) version of chart.js, the x axis option is wrong, and you get an error in console "Invalid scale configuration for scale: xAxes". You should have it as scales:{x: {type: "time"}}. Then, you have to include one of the available adapters. See your code with luxon adapter jsFiddle. Unrelatedly, smoothing the curve may be achieved by setting a tension greater than 0 and less than 1.
